# Can I make validated_uniqueness_of fail silently in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Title has it all...

I want a unique constraint on a column, but if a record tried to get created with that restraint, just fail.

or... should I just be using first_or_initialize / first_or_create?

Answer (score 4):

`first_or_create` / `first_or_initialize` is for when you are okay with it returning an existing record/instance rather than creating/instantiating a new one. If that's the behavior you want, then maybe you should go that route.

---

**Short version of the rest of this answer**: *"Why are you writing a constraint that then gets ignored? This sounds fishy."*

But since you said you want it to just fail, consider the following:

What's the point of the constraint if it's going to be silent? That would hide a problem, and you don't want that. Your app/DB is like, *"Hey, man, you told me to **always** reject this non-unique crap, but now you've changed your mind?"* You use these failures to keep your data valid and to pass errors back to the user so they can correct things.

If you only need to enforce uniqueness in some cases, but it's okay to avoid it in other situations (this would be weird, but I've heard weirder) then you need to seriously consider the design of that piece of code. It's definitely best if you can definitively say, *"This should **either always** be unique, **or never care** about being unique - one or the other."* If that's what you need then you'll have to remove any uniqueness constraint at the DB level (because you cannot conditionally ignore those) and make it a conditional constraint at the Rails model level. But be **very careful** if you go this route. Once you have non-unique data in your table you won't be able to easily go back if you need to, and you might paint your future self into a terrible corner of invalid data.

If the uniqueness constraint is failing because of non-user supplied data (i.e. you're creating a record inside your app that is completely independent of user input of any kind) **then you have a bug in your code** and should address that, since you should be able to prevent uniqueness constraint errors inside your own code 100% of the time.

If this is a temporary thing, maybe you're creating a record based on a 3rd party data source that is broken/has a bug, but you can't fix it right now or can't control it, yet you need your app to keep working, then it might be helpful if you ask a more specific question about your situation, because temporary workarounds are a category all their own. Some are decently engineered workarounds or patches while others tend to become horrible hacks that will cost you maintenance time down the line.

Answer (score 1):

yes you should be using first_or_create
here is the example:

```
Client.where(:first_name => 'Andy').first_or_create(:locked => false)
# => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Andy", orders_count: 0, locked: false, created_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27", updated_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27">
```